# Ngrx Store Resets after browser refresh. How to make the application preserve the state?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I Dispatch a action from one component

```
this.store.dispatch({type : STORE_TEAMCREST , payload : team.crestURI});
```

and in the other component i select from the store using

```
this.store.select(state => state.table.teamCrest).subscribe(data => this.teamCrest = data);
```

This works fine if my app is going sequentially backward or forward, but once i do a browser refresh the state loses it's value. How to preserve it's value so that it works on browser refresh?

Comment: You have to user either cookies or local storage so on init you can check the previous state and every time you make a change rewrite your local storage or cookie.

Comment: @EduardoVargas any other to acheive this

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your store has a `subscribe` function which will be called any time an action is dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have changed. For a simple solution, you could persist the state to local storage here:

```
this.store.subscribe(function() {
    localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(this.store.getState()));
})
```

[Documentation here](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#subscribe)

Notice that you will need to stringify your state to store it in local storage

To use this state, you will need to pass the local storage state `localStorage.getItem('state')` (if it exists) as your default state in your reducer. To achieve this, i normally have a helper function check whether an item with key 'state' exists in local storage and calls JSON.parse on the value if it exists.

default reducer case:

```
default:
        if (retrieveState()) {
            var newState = JSON.parse(retrieveState())          
            return newState
        }
        else {
            return {...whatever your default state is};
        }
```

Also after a quick look around, there does appear to exist a middleware which should achieve what you are wanting: https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Comment: how to retive when using store,select the state will it be updated or we need to fetch from local storage ?

Comment: you continue to use store.select the same way. your store.subscribe function just ensures that the in-memory store is backed up should you kill your in-memory session

Comment: where do i place this subscribe call ? at the roor level or featured level as i have lazy loaded modules 2

Comment: i have accepted the answer but i feel as my ngrx component shave lazy loading it is not working properly as when refreshing from lazy loaded components it only fires the parent actions

Comment: Can somebody explain with ngRx needs LocalStorage?  I thought ngRx was supposed to *be* local storage on steroids.

Comment: @NickHodges You should think of it more as an in-memory cache. Persistence would be a plus but alas. luckily this middleware exists