# Is this a persist state issue? Ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

When I navigate with angular routerLink, the following code works fine.

However, if I refresh the page, I get `undefined` value.

```
this.sub = this._route.fragment.subscribe((collectionKey: string) => {
       this.store.dispatch( new actions.Select(collectionKey));
       const col = this.store.select(fromStore.getSelectedCollection);
       col.subscribe(collection => this.collection = collection);
       console.log(this.collection)
    });
```

Is there anyway out to solve this?

Comment: iMO nested subscribes are a time bomb

Comment: Can you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right state is not persistent. This post can answer you question.

[Ngrx Strore Resets after browser refresh , How to make the application preserve the state ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45587050/ngrx-strore-resets-after-browser-refresh-how-to-make-the-application-preserve)